# Facebook Comments on my webstie. Is it legal?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I've got one question. I want to add plugin Facebook comments to my commercial website, for my users. They will able to write opinion and comments for my work. If I'll add plugin, should I pay anything for facebook or facebook comments plugin on my website is illegal?
P.S. I haven't got Faceebook Developer account.

Answer (score 0):

> should I pay anything for Facebook

No, Facebook [Social Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) are free, but must be used under Facebook policies.

> facebook comments plugin on my website is illegal

No, why do you think that? it's not illegal unless you break the policy

> I haven't got Faceebook Developer account.

basically you don't need a one, but you **should verify your account, create an app and use it insights, in other yes, you need a developer account again, free of cost**

So go ahead and [grab your code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/)